# Find solution of $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+p^2y=0, p \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The following differential equation is given:

$$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+p^2y=0, p \in \mathbb{R}$$

- Find the general solution of the differential equation at the interval $(-1,1)$ (with the method of power series).
- Are there solutions of the differential equation that are polynomials?

That's what I have tried:

We are looking for a solution of the form $y(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ with radius of convergence $R>0$.

$$y'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n x^{n-1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) a_{n+1} x^n$$

$$y''(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)n a_{n+1}x^{n-1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} x^n$$

$$-x^2y''(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -n(n-1)a_n x^n$$

We have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2}-n(n-1) a_n-na_n+p^2a_n\right]x^n=0, \forall x \in (-R,R)$$

It has to hold:

$$(n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2}+ \left[ -n(n-1)-n+p^2\right] a_n=0 \\ \Rightarrow (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+ \left[ -n(n-1+1)+p^2 \right]a_n=0 \\ \Rightarrow a_{n+2}=\frac{n^2-p^2}{(n+2)(n+1)} a_n \forall n=0,1,2, \dots$$

For $n=0: a_2=-\frac{p^2}{2}a_0$

For $n=1: a_3= \frac{1-p^2}{2 \cdot 3} a_1$

For $n=2: a_4= \frac{(2^2-p^2)(-p^2)}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot  4 } a_0$

For $n=3: a_5=\frac{(3^2-p^2)(1-p^2)}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5}a_1$

For $n=4: a_6=\frac{(4^2-p^2)(2^2-p^2)(-p^2)}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6}a_0$

For $n=5: a_7=\frac{(5^2-p^2)(3^2-p^2)(1-p^2)}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7}$

So:

$$a_{2n}=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (2i)^2-p^2}{(2n)!} a_0$$

$$a_{2n+1}=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (2i+1)^2-p^2}{(2n+1)!} a_1$$

So the solution $y$ can be written as follows:

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n}x^{2n}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$

Is it right so far? If so, then do we have to find for  the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n}x^{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$ the radius of convergence and show that they define functions that are infinitely many times differentiable?

If so, then do we have to take the ratio

$$\left| \frac{a_{2(n+1)} x^{2(n+1)}}{a_{2n} x^{2n}}\right|$$

? If yes, could we deduce something from the latter about the radius of convergence?

Comment: this is well known equation called the lengendre equations.

Answer (score 3):

Those ratios simplify rather nicely, so you can indeed deduce something about the radius of convergence.  But in fact there is a general theory that says there should be analytic solutions in any region (in the complex plane) where the coefficients are analytic and the leading coefficient is nonzero.  In this case the only bad points are $x = \pm 1$ where the leading coefficient is $0$, so the radius of convergence should be (at least) 1.

Also note what happens for integer values of $p$.

By the way (though this is not really connected to the power-series method), the substitution $x = \sin(z)$ produces something nice (equivalently, substitute $y(x) = u(\arcsin(x))$ in to the differential equation and simplify).

EDIT: For the ratio test, note that as $n \to \infty$, if $p$ is not an  integer
$$ \dfrac{a_{2(n+1)} x^{2(n+1)}}{a_{2n} x^{2n}} = \dfrac{((2n)^2-p^2) x^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)} \to x^2 $$
and similarly for $a_{2(n+1)+1} x^{2(n+1)+1}/(a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1})$, so the radii of convergence of the series are $1$.

If $p$ is an integer, one of the factors $(2i)^2 - p^2$ or $(2i+1)^2 - p^2$ is $0$, which makes either $\sum_{n} a_{2n} x^{2n}$ or $\sum_n a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ a polynomial.

Comment: Could you explain me further how we deduce that the radius of convergence is at least $1$?
$$$$
Also what happens for integer values of $p$ ?

Comment: Which version: the ratio test or the general theory?

Comment: Why do we conclude from the fact that $\frac{a_{2(n+1)} x^{2(n+1)}}{a_{2n} x^{2n}} \to x^2$ that the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n} x^{2n}$ is equal to $1$?Is the radius of convergence equal to the limit of $\frac{a_{2(n+1)}}{a_{2n}}$ ? Or is there an other reason?
$$$$
Also, in order that a solution of the differential equation  is a  polynomial, doesn't both of the series $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ and $\sum_n a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ have to be polynomials? Or am I wrong?

Comment: 1) If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \dfrac{a_{2(n+1)} x^{2(n+1)}}{a_{2n} x^{2n}}\right| < 1$, the Ratio Test says the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n} x^{2n}$ converges. If that limit $> 1$, it says the series diverges. So if the limit is $x^2$, the series converges for $|x| < 1$ and diverges for $|x| > 1$, i.e. the radius of convergence is $1$.  More generally, when $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{a_{2(n+1)}}{a_{2n}}\right| = L$ exists and is nonzero, the radius of convergence is $1/\sqrt{L}$.

Comment: 2) If $p$ is even, $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ is a polynomial, that (with $a_0 \ne 0$) is a nontrivial solution that is a polynomial.  Same for $\sum_n a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ with $a_1 \ne 0$ and $p$ odd.  You can have either one, but not both.  So it's never the case that all solutions are polynomials.

Comment: One of the series $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ or $\sum_n a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ is a polynomial if $p$ is an even or odd number respectively between $0$ and $(2n-1)^2$. Or am I wrong?
$$$$
Also since we know that it cannot hold simultaneously that $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ and $\sum_n a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ are polynomials, do we deduce that  there are no  solutions of the differential equation that are polynomials?

Comment: Thinking about it again, if $p$ is an even polynomial between $0$ and $(2(n-1))^2$ then $a_{2n}=0, \forall n \geq n_0$ some $n_0$. So only in this case $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ is a polynomial, right?

Comment: With $p$ an even integer, $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 0$, $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ is a solution that is a polynomial.  With $p$ an odd integer, $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$, $\sum_n a_{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ is a solution that is a polynomial. Those are the only cases where you have polynomial solutions (other than $0$).

Comment: I haven't understood why in any case one of the factors $(2i)^2-p^2$ or $(2i+1)^2-p^2$ is $0$ if $p$ is an integer.
$$$$
Why if $p$ is an integer, $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$ then the series $\sum_n a_{2n} x^{2n}$ is a polynomial? And why wouldn't it be the case if $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: Let's say $p$ is an even positive integer.  Then for $2i = p$, $(2i)^2 - p^2 = 0$.  That makes $a_{2n} = 0$ for all $n > i$.  On the other hand, if $a_1 = 0$ then all $a_{2n+1} = 0$.  So all but finitely many coefficients are $0$, which means the series is a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The Equation can be rewritten as( D^2-(x/(1-x^2))×D+x^2/1-x^2)y=0.
This equation can easily be solved using one integral method .
As P+XQ=0 then solution will assume type of y=xv.
substitute dy/dx by xdv/dx+v ,d^2y/dx^2 by xd^2/dx^2+2dv/dx and y by xv
This equation will be converted to linear diffrential equation with constant coefficient or other forms which r very easy to evaluate.

Comment: Please use mathjax formatting